# How to substitute <br> tags with something non visible, to replace them with HTML entities?

Tags: html, oracle, jsp, xslt

I'm using XSLT to create a table to my JSP page. The data is selected from oracle database, and the DESCRIPTION column can contain new lines and carriage returns `chr(10) chr(13)`. So the table is populated to the page, and I can see all rows listed there. When I click a row, the data is inserted into the input fields, which are responsible to insert new data to the table, or modify one after clicked.

So to have new lines in the input fields, I'm first replacing all `chr(10) chr(13)` characters to `< br/>` tags, when the table is populated:

```
public static final String CTRL_XML_PARAM2="<field name='REPLACE(REPLACE(description, CHR(13)), CHR(10), &apos;&lt;br/&gt;&apos;) as DESCRIPTION'>";
```

It's needed, because I cant replace the `chr(10) chr(13)` characters with new line HTML entities, only the `< br/>` tags when clicked:

```
document.frmTableList.DESCRIPTION.value=document.all['row_'+id].cells(1).innerText.replace(/<br\s*[\/]?>/gi, '&#13;&#10;');
```

The problem is the showing `< br/>` tags in the table. I've tried to replace the characters to non breaking spaces, and then replacing those:

```
public static final String CTRL_XML_PARAM4="<field name='REPLACE(REPLACE(description, CHR(13)), CHR(10), &apos;&&nbsp;&apos;) as DESCRIPTION'>";
document.frmTableList.DESCRIPTION.value=document.all['row_'+id].cells(1).innerText.replace(/&nbsp;/g, '&#13;&#10;')
```

But oracle has problems to replace to HTML entities.

What would be the appropriate character to insert into the table on the page, when populating it from the database? I'm looking for some none visible character or something.

Comment: Looks very similar to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44151759/oracle-db-sql-query-syntax-to-replace-to-new-lines-with-html-entities)

Comment: yeah kind of, but there is an extra step here